# form submit re-renders page in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit, rerender

I have a form in a react component.

When I click the submit button, I call signin(). In signin(), an error occurs as I can see the output in the chrome console, but it flashes by so quickly, I can't read it. Then the page refreshes and the error message is gone from the console.

Why is my form re-rendering the page? And how can I suppress the re-rendering so that I can read the error?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './login.scss';
import axios from '../axios/axiosInstance';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.usernameRef = React.createRef();
        this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
    }

    signin() {
        axios.get('/auth', {headers: {
            username: this.usernameRef.current.value,
            password: this.passwordRef.current.value}}).then(response => {
                console.log('response=', response);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('err=', err);
            });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="login-container">
                <form onSubmit={this.signin}>
                    <div className="flex-row-end">
                        <div className="form-element flex-column-end">
                            <input type="text"
                                placeholder="Username or email"
                                name="username"
                                ref={this.usernameRef}
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-element flex-column-end">
                            <input type="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                name="password"
                                ref={this.passwordRef}
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div className="login-submit">
                            <button className="submit-login-button" type="submit"><i className="fas fa-sign-in-alt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Login;
```

As you can see, in signin(), I am using axios to send a request to my backend with user credentials. On the backend, the logs show no record of receiving the request. Therefore, the error must be happening before the request is sent. But I need a way to suppress the re-rendering of the page so that I can see what the error message is.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature of `signin` to take the form submission event, you'll need to prevent the default action on it. This keeps the page from reloading.

```
signin(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that reference from component is not define yet.
Because method is not bound to `this` when used as a function:

```
 <form onSubmit={e => this.signin(e)}>
```

and then put `e.preventDefault()` inside `signin(e)` which prevent the blink after you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken axios will make the http request asynchronous, so you might have to use the [event.persist()](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) if this is not the case, preventDefault() should work as they mentioned in the answers above, also it is [recommended to call the api in the](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) componentDidMount()